# Watin AddDialogHandler method throwing null reference exception in FF

Tags: watin

I'm trying to add ConfirmDialogHandler to dialog handler and i get NullReferenceException.
This happens on FF 3.6 with latest watin version, the same code works on IE7 and 8.

```
   ConfirmDialogHandler confirmDialogHandler = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
   browser.AddDialogHandler(confirmDialogHandler); // --> exception here
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old Solution**

Found the problem.

The DialogWatcher was not initialized when FF session was created added this line to watin code:

```
    private void CreateFireFoxInstance(string url)
    {
        Logger.LogAction("Creating FireFox instance");

        UtilityClass.MoveMousePoinerToTopLeft(Settings.AutoMoveMousePointerToTopLeft);

        var clientPort = GetClientPort();
        clientPort.Connect(url);
        _ffBrowser = new FFBrowser(clientPort);
        StartDialogWatcher();  // <-- Added line
        WaitForComplete();
    }
```

**Please Note - This is the workaround**

The provided solution didn't worked
This is my workaround:
I used AutoIt dll and handled the popups by my self, code sample:

```
    using AutoItX3Lib;

    public static void RunAutomaticEnterCommand(Session session)
    {
        var autoIt = GetPopupHandle();
        autoIt.Send("{ENTER}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Cancel the popup
    /// For FF
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="session"></param>
    public static void RunAutomaticCancelCommand(Session session)
    {
        var autoIt = GetPopupHandle();
        autoIt.Send("{TAB}");
        autoIt.Send("{ENTER}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the autoit popup handler
    /// AutoIt is a script language, we using it to handle the firefox popups
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static AutoItX3Class GetPopupHandle()
    {
        var autoIt = new AutoItX3Class();
        autoIt.AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 2);
        const string partialTitle = "The page at"; //the popup in Firefox starts with this text
        autoIt.WinWait(partialTitle, "", 30);
        string fullTitle = autoIt.WinGetTitle(partialTitle); //Get the whole popup title

        autoIt.WinActivate(fullTitle); //Get focis to the popup
        if (autoIt.WinWaitActive(fullTitle, "", 20) == 0)
        {
            reporter.Report("Failed to get the FireFox popup handle", false);
            return autoIt;
        }
        return autoIt;
    }
```